# Dropdown Grid and List View

Tags: jquery, html

I am in need of some help. I recently had a design change from a simple toggle to having the Grid and List view options to be inside of a dropdown. Im a little stuck right now on how to edit what i have or even develop a new way of handling this. I need help getting the selected item to populate the button after it is clicked. I have the grid list view working great. Im just lost on how to achieve this dropdown right now and could use a little help. Here is my HTML code so far:

[image]

[image]

HTML:

```
 <div class="list-view col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle toggle-view" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-icon-grid-view"></span>&nbsp;Grid <span class="hidden-txt hidden-xs">&nbsp;View</span></button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" id="grid" class="btn btn-sm grid-view-btn btn-sm-toggle form-control active"><span class="icon-icon-grid-view"></span>&nbsp;Grid <span class="hidden-txt hidden-xs">&nbsp;View</span><span class="down-icon icon-icon-down-arrow visible-xs"></span></a>
        <a href="#" id="list" class="btn btn-sm list-view-btn btn-sm-toggle form-control"><span class="icon-icon-list-view"></span>&nbsp;List <span class="hidden-txt hidden-xs">&nbsp;View</span><span class="down-icon icon-icon-down-arrow visible-xs"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you have any css ?

Comment: I do. I am trying to make a codepen but it seems all dropdowns break in here for some reason. Nothing is dropping down or seems to be working im sure im missing something. Give me a second. I really dont want to post all of my scss since it has a lot of other elements in there which are apart of the same component and would get confusing.

Comment: i would say the simplest way to do it is add a ul li reference here and style it according to that

Comment: I was thinking that also. The issue i foresee is the mobile break down which shows "Grid" and "List" on the page inline. Im posting that pic now. Here is the code pen for now. I will try to update it as i figure things out.

Comment: https://codepen.io/thrilom/pen/prxrOR

Comment: here is something to get you started on and let me know if this doesn't make sense https://jsfiddle.net/yrn3dqqo/1/

Comment: I have the dropdown and toggling working the issue i am having is that i need the selection the user clicks to populate the button after clicked. I think from there I will need someway of displaying bother "Grid" and "List" view inline for mobile. I do not think manipulating the DOM is right here. I also do not want to show a dropdown for desktop devices and hide it for mobile and show the 2 buttons for mobile. I would like this to be a simple solution if there is one. I surely do not mind changing it to an unordered list if needed. Thank you In advance Keith I appreciate your time helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153039/discussion-between-keith-and-user2025730).